# can use orWhere and Where functions with delete

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2

Yii2 framework why i cant use this?

```
$rows = new Query;
$rows->createCommand()
    ->delete('friends')
    ->Where(['userid' => 1 ,'userid' => 2])
    ->orWhere(['userid' => 2 ,'userid' => 1])
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the  where() and or orWhere() function you are using an hash format  (['key'=> 'value'])

> **Hash Format** Hash format is best used to specify multiple
>   AND-concatenated sub-conditions each being a simple equality
>   assertion. It is written as an array whose keys are column names and
>   values the corresponding values that the columns should be.

Lookin to you code This is equivalent to

```
 where userid = 1 and userid = 2
```

look a this for na useful guide  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

second but most important .. in Yii2 you have delete()  and deleteAll()

> **delete()** Deletes the table row corresponding to this active record.
>
> **deleteAll()**  Deletes rows in the table using the provided conditions.

Answer (score 0):

this is working code

```
$rows->createCommand()->delete('friends',['userid' =>[1,2], 'friendid' =>[1,2])->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Friends::deleteAll(['and',
            [ 'userid'=>3],
            ['in', 'userid', [1,5,7]]]
        );
```

Comment: haha it's funny, I asked this question 2 years, 9 months ago :D :D

Comment: May some one still need an answer.